# Is there such a variety as "Standard Black English”, spoken by educated African Americans, or is it just a racist phrase?

Tags: phonology, varieties, racism

Standard Black English – (1980, coined by Orlando Taylor) The Standard English of black Americans.

> Taylor points out the fact that most educated African Americans speak “standard black English”.  They adopt the grammar of standard English, with all the necessary inflections, but do so with distinctive black English phonology.  (John Baugh, 1990)

The possible duplicate at [Why is there "Black English" but not "White English"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/183178/why-is-there-black-english-but-not-white-english) addresses the dialect as spoken in ghetos, but not the English of ***educated*** African Americans. In addition, although we can always listen to educated African Americans on TV these days, from Mr Obama to Oprah Winfrey or Colin Powell, and make up our minds about the subject, I would like to learn what is consensual among linguists.

Comment: Should this be on Linguistics?

Comment: I think the answer is of general interest.

Comment: Like all languages, [African American Vernacular English (AAVE)](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/ebonics.lsa.html) has many dialects; like all vernacular languages, it doesn't have a standard dialect. So "Standard Black English" is a misnomer; don't bother looking further for it. Most black Americans are polylectal, controlling a portion of the spectrum of dialects and sociolects, just like speakers of white-bread English do. But in the case of black Americans, -- as in the case of latino Americans -- there is a broader range of diversity and a corresponding broader range of cultures.

Comment: We don't say *Standard Southern English* for people who speak grammatical English with a Southern accent, so maybe we shouldn't use *Standard Black English* for people who speak grammatical English with an African-American accent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking from personal experience as an "educated African-American," most people who belong in that category have mastered a range of variations on English, and can can switch easily between them based on context (see [Code Switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching)).  This does include a register that is reliably associated, in particular, with being both educated and African-American --think Cornel West or Dr. Martin Luther King for two different flavors of this register.

This register plays a specific function: It signals the listener than one is both educated and black, and ashamed of neither.  Most people who can access this register, however, can additionally evoke the entire spectrum of registers from fully standard English to full black vernacular, and will adjust based on audience and intent.

Given that, I wouldn't personally characterize this register as either distinctive or consistent enough to be considered its own dialect, nor would I consider *Standard Black English* to be either a good descriptor or a good conceptualization of this concept.

*Note: I'd be interested to see if there have been identifiable generational differences in this register, given socioeconomic and cultural changes in black America as related to the American mainstream --that's a separate question, however.*

Comment: Interesting jargon use of 'register'. What does that mean in plain English, and how does it connect with plain English uses of register?

Comment: @DominicCronin As defined by Wikipedia, "a register is a variety of a language used for a particular purpose or in a particular social setting."  I'm not a linguist myself, but I believe it's a commonly used term in the field.  The Wikipedia article contains the history and derivation of the term if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

In my linguistics studies (both undergraduate and graduate courses) I had not heard the term "Standard Black English" until very recently, and that was in my own research:

Hoover, M. R. (1978). Community attitudes toward Black English. Language in Society, 77, no. 1: 65-87

(Just a note that everything I am about to say is in the context of English in the United States). Something to keep in mind is that within linguistics (because of the varying branches and reasons for engaging the discipline) there are sometimes different terms used to describe the same concept and there are sometimes the same term found describing different concepts; thus, this idea of a consensus is often not going to be found in a concrete way. Yes, most linguists (of whom I'm aware) acknowledge that there is a Standard Black English (whether it is termed as such or not) in which the speaker uses "Standard English" in the sense of straying from the syntactical markers of "Vernacular" Black English (AAVE, BVE, etc.), but still uses, as your quote points out, a phonology distinct from "Standard English" (I put "Standard" in quotes because there is no such thing--everyone speaks with some accent, in some dialect).

What it boils down to is that linguists are generally aware of the social stigma that comes with speaking AAVE and that some black speakers, to avoid that stigma, will use "Standard Black English" in certain settings (you might think of it as a register, but I could be technically wrong there). Hope that helps.

Comment: I think this answer is generally OK, but I disagree that the primary motivation to use this register is to avoid the stigma associated with AAVE --or at least, I don't think that explanation comes close to telling the full story.

Comment: @ChrisSunami While, yes, the article I cited is quite aged (1978), her research actually does indicate that the code-switch from "Vernacular Black English" to "Standard Black English" is indeed informed by an awareness of extant racism (stigma) that could be socially, educationally, and professionally damning. However, I agree that there is surely something more at work in these code-switching decisions.

Comment: In my experience, anyone who can use this register could also use completely standard English if he or she chose, therefore the question not just "why not use AAVE instead?" but also, "why not use SE instead?"  The answer to the second question cannot be to avoid stigma, since SE is not stigmatized.  It seems that your source is considering only the first question.

Answer (score -2):

Educated African Americans don't have their own 'dialect' or their own 'standard English'. As mentioned in the question there are enough educated people on TV who's English is no different than any other educated person with a different racial background.

The only 'standard' black English might be found in the following (but it wouldn't exactly be found coming out of the mouths of, so-called, educated people):

**Ebonics**

> American black English regarded as a language in its own right rather than as a dialect of standard English. *Oxford Dictionary of English*

**Jive** (too much Airplane?)

> 1. (also jive talk) [mass noun] a form of slang associated with black American jazz musicians. *Oxford Dictionary of English*

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Edited now to, hopefully, include an answer to the question.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem very useful --it doesn't give any consideration to the actual existence of speech patterns distinctive to educated black Americans, or even indicate any familiarity with the phenomenon.