# The origin of "conversate"

Tags: etymology, non-standard

I'm trying to explain the origin of the non-standard word "conversate" that is used in some circles. My theory is that it came out of an attempt to make the commonly used noun "conversation" into a verb by adding the suffix "ate" in the same manner that other standard english verbs are derived. 
For example:

> noun: donation
>        verb: donate
>
> noun: allocation
>        verb: allocate
>
> noun: appropriation
>        verb: appropriate

What is the specific linguistic term for applying a perceived rule/pattern to other words incorrectly?

This is an example of ______?

Comment: @Josh61  So the term is "back-formation"? Can I say, "this is an example of back-formation"?

Comment: I'd definitely call it back-formation. You could say it was back-formated.

Comment: OP: Yes.
@sumelic I’d add an additional “t,” spelling it “back-formatted.”

Comment: Back-formation it a general term for any new term formed from an exiting one: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/back-formation

Comment: @RobShort- I think you missed sumelic’s joke.

Comment: @jim [Slaps own forehead.] Ouch. Man, did I ever.

Comment: Got it.  Deleting my semi-snarky comment! :-)

Answer (score 1):

An instance of *verbalizing or verbalization.*

***To [verbalize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/verbalize):***

> - (Linguistics) to change (any word that is not a verb) into a verb or derive a verb from (any word that is not a verb).

(Collins Dictionary)

***To [conversate](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=conversate%20&searchmode=none) (v.):***

> - by 1994, apparently a back-formation from conversation or an elaboration of converse. According to some, from U.S. black English.

(Etymonline)

Comment: Jesus, that tacked-on “According to some, from U.S. black English” in the Etymonline citation is some _seriously_ repugnant racist sh*t.

Comment: @Rob Short: It depends on your preconceptions. If you consider all back-formations ignorant, and you consider any attribition of ignorance to black people racist, then I can see how the Etymonline citation could be considered racist. But as a descriptive source, Etymonline doesn't make any normative judgements (as far as I know). Whether the statement is shit (false) is a question of fact. It would be interesting to know if there is any factual basis to the claim is, and if so, what it is.

Comment: @sumelic Disagree. Disagree completely. Your logic only holds if you can find instances on Etymonline that make specific reference to a word originating “from U.S. White English.” Don’t give me that “I’m against affirmative action because it’s demeaning to the underrepresented groups it professes to help” garbage. 

It’s the mealy-mouthed “According to some” that I’m talking about. It’s like saying “Well, don’t tell anyone _I_ said so, but..."

Comment: Additionally, is it really best practices to cite something attributed to “some”? Who is this “some”? Why should I care anything about what “some” says? Is “some” credentialed in some way?

Comment: @RobShort: It doesn't seem best practices at all. As I said, I don't see any factual basis to the claim, so I have no idea if it's true or not. It seems likely to me that a simple back-formation like this would arise multiple times, rather than coming from any one speech community. I'm confused why reference to "white English" is necessary to make "black English" a legitimate term. Would you also consider it racist to say that the word "jazz" comes from black English?

Comment: @all We have to be able to quote texts which may be considered racist here: this is a site about language, and different races have different styles and practices of English. That's why we talk of AAVE, BrE, Indian English, Singaporean English, and so on. Etymonline's comment is not racist *per se;* but it **is** calling out a potential racist attitude amongst those who hold that that is the origin. That there are some who hold "The origin is US Black English" is likely to be an objective fact. It doesn't make those people right or that term of phrase desirable, but it's not wrong to quote it.

Comment: - with all respect to everyone's sensibility, I think the sencence was overstressed in its meaning which, as suggested, is most likely just an objective one.

Comment: @sumelic The reference to white English is necessary because in the absence of any words with “white English” designation, and by virtue of its specificity, the “black” in “black English” indicates a deviation from some standard form of English. And if there’s nothing labeled “white English” (only “black English,” “latino English”) it’s further implied that “white English” is the standard, normative, “correct” form of English.
The Q. about “jazz” coming from black English simply isn’t analagous/misses the point. Why would I object to the specific historical/cultural context of a word's origin?

Comment: @RobShort: I guess the following question is relevant: [Why is there “Black English” but not “White English”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/183178/why-is-there-black-english-but-not-white-english)

Answer (score 1):

It’s most commonly called “back-formation.”